# WinRM on Azure RM VM

Tags: powershell, azure, winrm

I'm trying to connect to an AzureRM VM. I've read through so many tutorials on WinRM but I still cannot get this to work:

```
    Enter-PSSession -ComputerName "$($HOST).cloudapp.net" -Credential $username
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

> The user name or password is incorrect. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic

When I add the -UseSSL param I get this error:

> The WinRM client cannot process the request because the server name cannot be resolved. For more information, see the 
>   about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

The credentials I'm entering are correct. So I also tried "localhost\$username" and I get a different error:

> The following error with errorcode 0x80090311 occurred while using Kerberos authentication:

So I tried to use -Authentication basic and I get:

> The WinRM client cannot process the request. Unencrypted traffic is currently disabled in the client configuration

But I have already checked and unencrypted traffic is enabled.

Has anyone come across this issue before? Any suggestions as to what to try next?

```
    credentials = Get-Credential -UserName $username -Message "Enter Azure account credentials"
    $continue=$false
    Do{
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "$($VMName).cloudapp.net" -Credential $credentials 
if ($session -ne $null)
{
  $continue=$true
}
Write-Output "Unable to create a PowerShell session . . . sleeping and trying again in 30 seconds."
Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
      }
   Until(
$continue=$true)
```

EDIT Adding what the settings are now on the Server:

```
   WSManConfig: Microsoft.WSMan.Management\WSMan::localhost\Client

Type            Name                           SourceOfValue   Value
----            ----                           -------------   -----
System.String   NetworkDelayms                                 5000
System.String   URLPrefix                                      wsman
System.String   AllowUnencrypted                               true
Container       Auth
Container       DefaultPorts
System.String   TrustedHosts
```

And the client:

```
   WSManConfig: Microsoft.WSMan.Management\WSMan::localhost\Client

 Type            Name                           SourceOfValue   Value
 ----            ----                           -------------   -----
 System.String   NetworkDelayms                                 5000
 System.String   URLPrefix                                      wsman
 System.String   AllowUnencrypted                               true
 Container       Auth
 Container       DefaultPorts
 System.String   TrustedHosts                                   @{Value = "XX.XX.XX.XX"}
```

Comment: well, username or password is incorrect... what do you expect...

Comment: I've tried this about 20 times and I assure you... the username and password I entered are the same ones I used when setting up the VM in Azure

Comment: I have been playing around more and I put in a few arbitrary hostnames to see if I had different error messages (like host not found) and I when I use the first command, I still get the error of username and password.

Comment: Are you certain you are using a credentials object for -Credentials? Try -Credential (Get-Credential -UserName $Username)

Comment: Yes, I am using the object... I've updated the OP with what I'm running.

Comment: Do your VM join some AD?

Comment: The reason I'm trying to connect to the remote host is actually to do just that.. I want to spool up the VM then connect to it and install AD and built the domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try to use the following cmdlets. I test in my lab. It works for me.

`$SecureString = Read-Host -AsSecureString 'Enter your password ' | ConvertFrom-SecureString | ConvertTo-SecureString
$MySecureCreds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "yourusername",$SecureString
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName "yourcomputername" -Credential $MySecureCreds`

I find a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736735/powershell-get-credentials-fails) with you, maybe you could check.

Update:

On **WinRM server**, please try to execute the following cmdlet.

`winrm quickconfig`

You will get the following messages.

> WinRM service is already running on this machine. WinRM is already set
>   up for remote management on this computer.

On  **client PC**, please try to execute the following cmdlet by using Administrator account.

`winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts = "server IP"}'`

Comment: I tried this and I get the exact same error message about username and password. I tried adding the mylocalmachine\ to the usename and I get the unencrypted traffic error. So basically I get the exact same errors... Also, why would you convert from a secure string only to pipe it to a convert to secure string?

Comment: @Jewtus I have update my answer, maybe you could try to configure `WinRM` on your service and client.

Comment: I've already done that on the machines but I have now included the settings. I did read that if you are trying to use WinRM for a machine without AD you need to setup and configure an SSL cert. Could that be the problem or is this a firewall configuration problem? Again I'm trying to do this against an Azure RM host.

Comment: Based on my knowledge, you don't need to setup and configure and SSL cert. If this is a firewall problem, I don't think you will get this error. It seems a client problem. Maybe you could try to use other PC by using the same cmdlet to test.

Comment: On client PC `winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts = "*"}'`

Comment: I have tried with * and with the IP in trustedhosts on the client machine but still no luck. I've also assigned a DNS to the IP address of the Azure host and tried to use the DNS as the machine name and I have the same issues.

Comment: Yes, using DNS name could not solve this problem. Based on my knowledge, you could try on other client PC or you could create a VM on Azure and test in the VM.

Comment: I tried a new azure VM and a different network with no network side configurations, set the allowunencypted on both client and server, set trusted hosts to * on both machines, and I'm getting a different error now:  WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the 
computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer.

Comment: I should also mention that I have used RDP on both machines to confirm they can see each other using the IP addresses, and I ran winrm quickconfig on both

Comment: Do you try to disable client PC's Windows Firewall? `telnet PublicIP  5985` to test winrm port is listening.

Comment: On your server `netstat -ant` port 5985 or 5986 should be listening.

Comment: Well I was not able to see the listener so i reconfigured it and now I see the listener on the server, I also have set up firewall exceptions on both client and host, but telnet <IP> 5985 still gets a connection failure. Is there a way to trace a call to see where it is failing?

Comment: I was able to get it working on a public network but not a private network... this is clearly a router/networking issue at this point. Thank you for the help Walter

Comment: @Jewtus yes, it seems a networking issue. Do you disable all Windows Firewall? Windows could disable private network access.

Comment: You could use `Microsoft Network Monitor` to capture the package. You could download it from the [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=4865)

Comment: If my answer is helpful, don't forget to mark me. It could help more people who meet the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Below parameter helps to connect the Azure VM through WINRM

```
    $hostName="DomainName" 
$winrmPort = "5986"
# Get the credentials of the machine
$cred = Get-Credential
# Connect to the machine
$soptions = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $hostName -Port $winrmPort -Credential $cred -SessionOption $soptions -UseSSL
```

Comment: Script to connect WIRM : $hostName="DomainName" 
$winrmPort = "5986"
$username = "UserName"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString “Password” -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (“$username”, $secpasswd)
$soptions = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $hostName -Port $winrmPort -Credential $mycreds -SessionOption $soptions -UseSSL